# Angular-Cli 'ng g c my-new-component' Error: Could not find (undefined) and Could not find (undefined)

Tags: angular, terminal, command-line-interface, angular-cli

**Problem:**

In my angular 5+ app project, in one of my subfolder, after I typed `ng g c my-component` commend, Nothing generated ,instead, it popup some unknown errors, anyone know what is going on here? I've reinstalled the npm/angular@cli for many times.

```
jocs@Jocs ~/r/s/a/pages (devReno)> ng g c my-new-component
Error: Could not find (undefined)
Could not find (undefined)
jocs@Jocs ~/r/s/a/pages (devReno) [1]> ng generate component my-new-component
Error: Could not find (undefined)
Could not find (undefined)
jocs@Jocs ~/r/s/a/pages (devReno) [1]>
```

[image: Terminal Screen Shot (image link)]

**Dev Environments:**

OS: darwin x64(Mac OS: 10.13.4)

Angular CLI: 1.7.4

Node: 9.11.1

Angular: 5.2.9

Comment: Has same problem. Downgrade angular-cli to 1.7.3 solves problem for me.

Comment: It did not help me

Comment: Joseph, Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem and I had to reinstall Angular Cli.

The way I reinstalled is by downgrading and then upgrading it back. I supposed you can also remove either the package from `node_modules` or doing `npm uninstall @angular/cli` and then `npm i @angular/cli@1.7.4`.

The way that worked for me was doing this:

My version of npm (version 6.0) will downgrade angular cli if I install a different version
`$ npm i @angular/cli@1.7.3`

Then I upgraded back to 1.7.4
`$ npm i @angular/cli@1.7.4`

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was that I had files and nodes directories in the root directory. I remove it.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm package-lock.json
```